# Validate access token for WEB API protected by Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I'm playing with Azure AD authentication and authorization scenarios and not all clear for me.
Currently I'm looking at [`SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet`](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet) sample project.

And one thing that I can't understand. On the client side we get access token using implicit grant flow - that is clear. Then we send request to WEB API with `Bearer` and access token as value. On the server side we have `TodoListController` with `Authorize` attribute. So, in order to hit the controller request must be authorized.

What is not clear how authentication middleware validates my access token (what if random text sent instead of valid access token?). I cloned katana project and investigated `WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationExtensions` and `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler` classes, but I still can't find concrete place where validation occur.
How my WEB API will know that this particular access token is valid and where is this concrete line of code, which is responsible for validation?

Thanks!

**UPD**:

Actually I find the place. All work is done inside `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler` in method `AuthenticateCoreAsync`:

```
tokenReceiveContext.DeserializeTicket(tokenReceiveContext.Token);
```

this call leads to running `JwtFormat.Unprotect` method, which performs actual validation.
Thanks @Aram for good notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your service start up you register OWIN and when your controller is decorated with Authorize attribute then the authentication challenge will happen and OWIN will try to validate the token on each request..

The token validation happens because you have OWIN Dll references AND you have the startup.auth class in your service project...

You probably have something like this, that you include Auth challenge in the service side:

```
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
        });
```

When the validation is happening, the OWIN middleware will validate against the Audience and the Tenant that the token has been acquired from, and if they dont match the Authz will fail...

Depending on with Authentication handler you use the actual code that calls the ValidateToken function is in YOUR_AUTH_HANDLERAuthenticationHandler class.

Here is the location for OpenId AuthZ handler:
http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs

For instance if you have OpenIdConnect Authz handler then the token validation is in : Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler class and the Overrride method :

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
```

And the ValidateToekn code will look like (if your AuthZ handler is OpenId connect):

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = Options.SecurityTokenHandlers.ValidateToken(openIdConnectMessage.IdToken, tvp, out validatedToken);
```

Comment: "OWIN middleware will validate against the Audience and the Tenant that the token has been acquired from, and if they dont match the Authz will fail" - I know that, but how it is done? Could you please point me on concrete line of code where this is happen?

Comment: thanks for an update. It works for OpenidConnect, but how it works for OAuth Bearer token? Look at the `OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler ` class, there is a line `await Options.Provider.ValidateIdentity(context);` where the validation should occur. `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider` is an implementation for `Options.Provider`. Look at the `ValidateIdentity` method - it invokes `OnValidateIdentity` delegate, which is setup in constructor - `context => Task.FromResult<object>(null);`. So, no validation at all. Am I missed something?

Comment: @Kai OnValidateIdentity is an extensibility point that allows you to perform additional validation against the identity that was generated when the token was processed by JwtFormat.cs. By default, the following are validated from artifacts found by querying the metadata endpoint: issuer, signature, lifetime, audience. If perhaps you wanted to ensure a specific claim existed, this is a good place to check as it would apply to all methods.